# how to make a class selector with condition about its spring?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li class='href-parent'> <a class='href'></a> </li>
```

I want all the 'li' tags with an 'a' tag with class 'href' to change color.

Comment: There's no way to accomplish this in CSS alone. [CSS Selectors Level 4 addresses this](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) (by appending an exclamation mark before the subject: `!li a.href`), but there's no support for that yet.

Comment: so i have to add another class to tag 'li'

Comment: If you don't want to use JavaScript (which is always a good idea), then yes, you'll have to add another class.

Comment: The good thing about classes is they're a space-separated list, so adding a new class shouldn't affect the rest of your page.

Comment: i thought css would be intelligent

Comment: @Joseph Silber: The syntax is not finalized yet unfortunately :( (and appending means after; prepending before)

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks for catching that. Late night. Pity we can't edit comments (after 5 minutes) 'round here...

Comment: Thank u all guys ! I have decided to add a new class to the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you can use `$('li.href-parent > a.href').parent().dosomething()`;

Comment: Or [`$('li:has(a.href)')`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) for that matter, but the OP wants to accomplish this in CSS.

Comment: yeah,jQuery is a good thing